# Not all GitLab Prometheus metrics are working

Tags: docker, gitlab, prometheus, metrics

I am relatively new to GitLab and struggle with making use of the metrics provided by GitLab.
I followed the steps described in the [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/monitoring/prometheus/gitlab_metrics.html) to activate the embedded Prometheus endpoint under `/admin/application_settings/metrics_and_profiling`.

When I curl the `/-/metrics` endpoint from the GitLab docker container, Prometheus is working and provides a subset of the available metrics.

The problem is, that Prometheus is not providing all of the available metrics. For example the following metrics are not working:

1. `gitlab.unicorn.workers`
2. `gitlab.transaction.event_push_branch_total`

But the metric `gitlab.puma.max_threads` is working fine.

Do I have to activate the other metrics somehow?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is stumbling on the same behavior, I found the problem for this.
After enabling Prometheus only those metrics are reported, that have been executed at least once.
After pushing a branch to the repo, the metric `gitlab.transaction.event_push_branch_total` was visible as well.